# How to set contenttype in razor (CSHTML)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In classic ASP.NET Web Forms view engine, we can set the ContentType in the .aspx page to the desired type.

Is there a direct/recommended equivalent in Razor?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should set a different content type in your action method.

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {
    Response.ContentType = "something";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Oh... I found this via Google but few people said that this didn't work. Thanks for the quick answer marcind :)

Comment: One follow up question... should I do it in the controller or in the view? @{ Response.ContentType = "..."; } I guess having it in the view is better.

Comment: If you were to follow seperation of concerns principles then I would argue that the view is the wrong place for this. The view's responsibility is the render the response to the output stream. I personally would either do it in the action method like above if it's a one-time thing. If I had multiple views that need a custom content type then I would write my own class that derives from `ViewResult` and return that instead of `View()`. However, you *can* write this code in the view itself so it's ultimately a question of preference. In the end you should do what get's your job done :)

Comment: Lol... I meant to type 'guess having it in the controller is better'. Now I come back and see that I had actually typed view :) But that resulted in a very detailed answer from you... for which I am thankful. I have already gone down the sub class route. Thanks for confirming my theory.

Comment: Not an expert on the subject, but I'd argue the content type can be really presentation specific without the action having to know about it? So could be the responsibility of the view without having to write extra code (custom ViewResult) for it.

Suppose you have 1 action with different views for html5 (text/html), xhtml(application/xhtml+xml), wap (text/vnd.wap.wml), the controller action doesn't need to know about HOW (choose which ViewResult inheritor) it's going to be presented, just WHAT it's going to present (the view model).

Comment: Don't forget to set `@{Layout=null}` in the view too :)

Comment: Hey, kid0m4n: Do you happen to remember why the google results you found recommend against using this method?  Might be useful info.

Comment: I put Response.ContentType = "text/javascript"; into my controller ActionResult and it didn't work, then I tried to put it into the razor view and it worked.

Comment: I believe this approach has an issue when used with output caching. See - https://stackoverflow.com/q/17088972

Answer (score 17):

That will work I just tested it, you can also add the following line to your cshtml:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
```

so that it looks something like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
}
```

It just depends on where you prefer to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
return Content(json, "application/json");
```